# Content expands vertically in IE but has a scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In my popup I have fixed the size, and if the inside content is larger there should come a vertical scrollbar, It works fine in firefox (though i only want vertical scrool bars) but does not work in IE(using IE 8). Below are the images. What could be the problem?

[image: Firefox Screenshot]
[image: Internet Explorer Screenshot]

My CSS code

```
#compareParentDiv
{ 
overflow-y: auto;
//overflow-x: hidden; 
max-height: 380px;
width:100%
}
```

My Div

```
$('#compareContent').empty();
    $('<div id="compareParentDiv" width="100%">'+
      '<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>'+
            '<div id="gridpager2"></div></div>')
    .appendTo('#compareContent');
```

Comment: You can set "overflow: auto" to the div that you want to add scrollbars to.

Comment: @Michas: It works in chrome and firefox but not in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`overflow-y:scroll`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) or `overflow-y:auto`, apply it on the element that should scroll.

If set to `scroll` scrollbars are always visible, if set to `auto` it's up to the browser but I believe that all browsers provide a scrollbar when needed but not otherwise.

Comment: I have added `overflow-y:auto` before, but no luck in IE. Check my code (Updated)

Comment: How do i disable horizontal scroll?